# How can I replace the verb references here?

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does references mean here? Can I rephrase this sentence?

Staff inputs the tracker number into the POS system, and the system references that number. http://www.fastcasual.com/articles/back-to-the-future-6-innovative-technologies-saving-restaurants-money-and-changing-the-industry/

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member of waiting staff gives a number of a tracking device to the Point-Of-Sale computer system, and leaves the tracking device with the customer.  The computer system then uses that number as a identifier for collating information on that customer on that occasion, such as what they have ordered at what time, and where they are.

So the verb *references* in the original quote corresponds to *uses that number as a identifier...*